# Display number of rows on printout

Tags: crystal-reports

If an Order contains 2 lines or more, my report sums it up and prints the whole quantity of items. It should print whichever line I have chosen:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemCount := ItemCount + 1;
ToText(ItemCount, "0") & "/"
    & ToText(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}),0,"")
```

For example, the order below contains a chair called Buzz, but the order contains 3 lines since each has different fabric. The total order quantity is 5:

[image]

If I print, the label count shows 1 out of 4 - which automatically sums the chair. If I select the first line, expected output is Buzz 1/2.. and 2/2. Currently output displays Buzz 1/4.. 2/4.. 3/4.. 4/4.. even if I just clicked 1st line. How can I achieve this result?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to reset the counter on each group. Just create a second formula and drop it in the group header:

```
global numbervar ItemCount := 0;
```

Comment: what do you mean? Shall I replace something or delete all my codes? Because currently I have the below code: WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemCount := ItemCount + 1;


ToText(ItemCount, "0") & "/" & ToText(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}),0,"")

Comment: Actually I think I may not be familiar enough with the latest version to help you here. My apologies.